# Start thrift server in standalone zeppelin

Tags: sql, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to access contents of spark.sql output via JDBC, like %sql interpreter does?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to setup Spark's thriftserver as described in the [Spark's documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.6/sql-distributed-sql-engine.html). Zeppelin is just consumer of the Spark's execution, and doesn't expose data itself.

If you really need to extract specific information from paragraph, you can use [Notebook API](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-preview2/usage/rest_api/notebook.html).